How was this question supposedly closed before it was even asked?
When looking at the closed question Hashcat when account name is "Not a real account", something caught my attention. It says it was asked 8 months ago, but closed 9 months ago:

However, in the history of the question, it was closed shortly after it was asked, which makes more sense than being closed before it was even asked:

Is this a bug, or is there a good reason for this peculiar behaviour?

Most possibly just a bug due to using different rounding.

As Andrew T commented, this is purely a rounding issue. For the closed date, it is rounded up to the next integer, and for the Asked date it is either rounded down or to the closest date (I can't remember which)
